# SSRS IIF then statement

Tags: ssrs-2012

I am trying to use IIF statement to get following results:

If Issuer = "U.S.Dollars" then sum all quantity else don't sum.

Statement I am using - =Sum(IIF(Fields!InvestmentIssuerNameLine1.Value = "U.S.Dollars (Cash)" , Fields!QtyEnd.Value)

Can somebody please help me in correcting this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting an error?

I think your only issue is that you don't have the else part of the IIF.

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!InvestmentIssuerNameLine1.Value = "U.S.Dollars (Cash)", Fields!QtyEnd.Value, 0) )
```

Comment: I still see quantity in multiple columns. I want to net all quantities in single line if issuer = "U.S.Dollars (Cash)".

Comment: What do you mean by **multiple columns**? This is meant to work as an expression. You can use it in multiple columns.